# How to use if condition in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that fetch records from two table. I want if condition in where clause with and operator.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT sfo.customer_id, sfo.increment_id FROM sales_flat_order sfo 
INNER JOIN  marketplace_partnertype mptype ON sfo.customer_id = mptype.partner_id 
WHERE (mptype.type = 'free' AND sfo.status='complete') AND IF @mptype.type=='free' THEN ((DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 5 DAY ))ELSE (DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY );
```

It shows syntax error near `IF @mptype.type=='free'`.

It should be appreciable if  some help to solve this issues.

Comment: for starters, what are you trying to compare those date values to in the `if`. which you shouldnt be using there anyway. what is you are trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of If condition is:

```
IF(<cond-expr>, <then-expr>, <else-expr>)
```

If we change the condition it will be like :-

AND IF `(@mptype.type=='free', (DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 5 DAY )) ,(DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY ))`

Query will look like:

```
SELECT sfo.customer_id, sfo.increment_id FROM sales_flat_order sfo 
INNER JOIN  marketplace_partnertype mptype ON sfo.customer_id = mptype.partner_id 
WHERE (mptype.type = 'free' AND sfo.status='complete')AND IF (@mptype.type=='free', (DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 5 DAY )) ,(DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY )))
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not correct, you can use case-when condition in the where condition as

```
SELECT sfo.customer_id, sfo.increment_id FROM sales_flat_order sfo 
INNER JOIN  marketplace_partnertype mptype ON sfo.customer_id = mptype.partner_id 
WHERE (mptype.type = 'free' AND sfo.status='complete')
and 
case 
 when @mptype.type = 'free' then  DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 5 DAY )
 else DATE( updated_at ) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY ) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use IF or CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
  sfo.customer_id,
  sfo.increment_id
FROM
  sales_flat_order sfo INNER JOIN  marketplace_partnertype mptype
  ON sfo.customer_id = mptype.partner_id 
WHERE
  (mptype.type = 'free' AND DATE(updated_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
  OR (mptype.type = 'complete' AND DATE(updated_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

but if you want to use case when you could do it this way:

```
WHERE
  mptype.type IN ('free', 'complete')
  AND DATE(updated_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL CASE WHEN mptype.type='free' THEN 3 ELSE 5 END DAY)
```